# Accessing xml files from a directory

Tags: bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting. I tried the below code for first checking whether any XML files exists in the specified directory. If one is found then I need to store the XML files in to the array to process the data. But the below lines are not working. What am I doing wrong? Please suggest the correct approach.

```
if [ -f ${Input_Path}/ABC/*.XML ] 
then
    arr=(${Input_Path}/ABC/*.XML)
    for i in "${arr[@]}";
        do
            .......
        done
```

Comment: An array is very likely not a good place to store an xml in. You do not specify what shell you use (bash?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350318/reading-an-array-from-a-file-in-bash-not-found-errors-using-cat

Comment: Can you describe how your script is not working? For example, if you show your expected output and compare it to the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below;

```
#!/bin/bash
Input_Path=$1
myarray=()

while IFS= read -rd '' files; do 
myarray+=("$files")
#do something;
done < <(find ${Input_Path} -type f -name '*.xml' -print0)

printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}"
```

run as below;

```
./script <yourInputPath>
```

ex:

```
user@user-host:/tmp/1$ ./test.sh /tmp/1
/tmp/1/2.xml
/tmp/1/4.xml
/tmp/1/3.xml
/tmp/1/1.xml
```